# I can't reorder favorite

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, dock

I can't reorder the favorite. When I move one, it finishes all the time in the first position. See picture

[image: Impossible to reorder favorite]

How can I reset/reinstall something to resolve this problem?

Comment: os version? [edit] accordingly

Comment: (venv)  ~  lsb_release -a                                     
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: I've edited that in for you. I'm using X11 (not Wayland) and I notice that you have to be quick grabbing the icon in the dock and moving it in one quick sweep and it's persistent. Which are you using? Use the terminal command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to check (it may be significant).

Comment: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` return `x11`

Comment: same as mine then. Did you try a quick fire grab and move and did it persist?

Answer (score 1):

In GNOME extension vertical-workspaces, desactivate the Dock option